# SharePoint 2013 - Page Status Bar

Tags: 2013

I want page status bar to be displayed on top of Main Content Place holder, not with the ribbon. What changes I need to do?

Comment: check out [this article](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/28/status-bar-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I don't think the status bar is part of the ribbon. Do you mean the status bar part of `<div id="DeltaPageStatusBar"></div>`?

Comment: Actually by default , it sticks to Ribbon, but I have custom master page, so I want this to be displayed in above content block, rather than with ribbon, because sometimes it gets hidden behind ribbon.

Comment: @Mark, I dont want any custom message to be displayed, neither I want to use any code behind, there should a way to do this by positioning it in masterpage layout.

Comment: @OvaisKhatri I haven't tested this, but since `DeltaPageStatusBar` is a `<SharePoint:AjaxDelta>` region, you could move that block inside the `<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderMain"></SharePoint:AjaxDelta>` block to force it to be part of the `DeltaPlaceHolderMain`. That might require some .css tuning afterwards.

Comment: @Moe I tried like this:  <div data-name="ContentPlaceHolderMain">
                <!--CS: Start PlaceHolderMain Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPageStatusBar" runat="server">-->
                <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
But it didn't work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up this by using javascript, with following snippet:

```
var element = $('#DeltaPageStatusBar').detach();
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain').prepend(element);
```